# how to config nginx when the server make redirect

Tags: nginx

I configured my Nginx to locate /doc to one of my local servers, just like this:

```
  location /doc {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
```

Then my server on 8000 port will make a redirect to **/message/html**

This is the problem...
The correct URL should be **/doc/message/html**

How can I config my Nginx to redirect the URL of /redirected_by_port_8000_server  to /doc/redirected_by_port_8000_server in the **location /doc block**

Comment: Take a look at the [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive. Use `curl -I` to identify the exact value of the `Location` response header that needs to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the URI. In nginx you will be able to pass `/doc` at the beginning of the URI by adding `/` at the end of the `proxy_pass` statement. It looks like below. Such that `http://whatever/doc` **->** `http://127.0.0.1:8000/doc`

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
```

However, the next proxy should rewrite by itself the `/doc` path and add it at its beginning. In nginx it would look like.

```
location /doc {
    rewrite ^/(.*) /$1/message/html/ break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Richard Smith.
I used **curl -I** checked the redirect location and changed my Nginx config file below:

```
  location /doc {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect https://$http_host https://$http_host/doc; #this will rewrite the redirect Location header
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
```